# Pass params on index_path route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes, link-to, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm having a helper for displaying the tags of a post

```
# Show action
%p Tags #{ link_tags @post }

# Helper
def link_tags post
  raw post.tag_list.map{ |t| 
    link_to t, posts_path(tag: t.name)
  }.join(', ')
end
```

However I'm getting an error on screen

```
undefined method `name' for "ruby":String
```

How can I fix this? As a side note the code on my sidebar (where I list all post-tags) where I tried to copy from works fine

```
- tag_cloud Post.tag_counts, %w(tag) do |tag, css_class|
    = link_to tag.name, posts_path(tag: tag.name), :class => css_class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post.tag_list` will give you an array of tags as strings.

What you are looking for is probably `post.tags` which should return an array of `ActsAsTaggableOn` objects.

Here you have [tutorial about tags on posts](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki/Tutorial-for-Posts)